# Disprove state space estimation

Tags: self-study, state-space-models

I am currently looking at a state space estimation procedure by Elliott & Timmermann (2016) which is apparently wrong. They suggest to (i) pick some H, F, Q and R, (ii) run the Kalman filter to obtain filtered state estimates $\xi_{t|t}$ and (iii) estimate the four system matrices by running linear regressions on the equations

$y_t = H\hat{\xi}_{t|t} +wt, \quad wt \sim N(0,R)\\\hat{\xi}_{t|t} =F\hat{\xi}_{t-1|t-1} + vt, \quad vt \sim N(0,Q)$,

where $y_t$ and $\hat{\xi}_{t|t}$ are treated as known, while $H$, $F$, $Q$ and $R$ are estimated by OLS. The idea is to repeat steps (ii) and (iii) until convergence. To disprove this procedure, it would be sufficient to show that the true parameters are not a fixed point. That is, I have to derive the distribution of $y_t-H\hat{\xi}_{t|t}$ under the true parameters. Similarly, I need to derive the distribution of $\hat{\xi}_{t|t} - F\hat{\xi}_{t-1|t-1}$ under the true parameters.

However, I am unable to derive the distribution on my own.. Could anyone please help me with this?

Comment: you  should add the self-study tag and read its wiki.